# How to preserve colors when capturing output from Git commands?

Tags: python, git, terminal, subprocess

I have a custom Git command implemented in Python that uses methods from the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module to call `git`. I've noted that, depending on the method used, the output may or may not be colored, e.g.:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('git push origin --delete foobar', shell=True)
print()
print(subprocess.run('git push origin --delete foobar', shell=True,
                     capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8').stderr, end='')
```

Output:

[image]

How to preserve colors in the captured output (both stdout and stderr)?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but consider using [the Python bindings for libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2) instead of `subprocess`. It should offer a nicer interface than having to build up strings as well as better performance and cross-platform support without needing `git` on the user's `$PATH`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force "git status" to output color on the terminal (inside a script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073708/force-git-status-to-output-color-on-the-terminal-inside-a-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many commands detect if they're not sending their output to a "terminal" and don't add the terminal-specific codes to display colors if not. That will be the case when you're missing the colors.  *Some* git commands, not sure all of them, can take a `--color` argument - check the manpages.

Comment: `push` doesn't take `--color`, that's the problem. I need some generic way to enable colors for all commands, whether the output goes to a terminal or not.

Comment: Short of rewriting git... try this question to see if it helps: [1401002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/how-to-trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdout-is-a-terminal-not-a-pipe?noredirect=1)

Comment: Yeah, using `script` or `unbuffer` is definitely an option. I was hoping there was an envariable enabling colors everywhere in Git, that would be ideal.