# How do I capture output of git commands with python subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I am trying to run a git command with subprocess and store the output as a string. When I run the se commands in the interpreter, the git command prints its output but it is not stored. If I trade out 'git status' with 'ipconfig', the command runs flawlessly and I can retrieve its output.

```py
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> p = sp.Popen('git status', stdout = sp.PIPE) #this one prints the output of git status after the >>> prompt is printed.
>>> a = p.communicate()
>>> a #is a tuple of (b'', None)
```

How do I capture the output of git commands with subprocess? Please do not mark this as a duplicate because I have tried solutions from all over the place. Some are listed here:

[How to preserve colors when capturing output from Git commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022549/how-to-preserve-colors-when-capturing-output-from-git-commands)
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators/

No matter what code I use, it does not work if applied to a git command. I use Windows 10 and Python 3.7.8.

Comment: Note that Git has a tendency to print *some* of its output to stderr, rather than stdout.

Comment: The real problem here is that you have no command named `git status`. You want `subprocess.run(['git', 'status'], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True).stdout`

Comment: git status still runs @triplee it just prints its output instead of piping it.

Comment: @torek That was the case here! Thank you!