# How to print out pdf file with script generated highlighted output?

Tags: shell, pdf

I've been used pidcat from JakeWharton to see the log of my app:

```
$ pidcat [org.test.myapp]
```

And redirect it to file:

```
$ pidcat [org.test.myapp] > ~/Dev/myapp_log
```

The pidcat generate pretty highlighted content that I try to keep it in the pdf file. That I've tried:

```
$ cupsfilter ~/Dev/myapp_log ~/Dev/myapp_log.pdf
```

But it just generate plain white text into pdf.

How could I keep the beautiful highlight format in the pdf file? P.S. It's a long log. Can't just print screen..

This is how the original output look like:

[image]

And here's partial pidcat output opened by default Text editor on Mac:

```
[107m                          [0m Process created for broadcast com.nortek.app/org.videolan.vlc.PhoneStateReceiver
[107m                          [0m PID: 9718   UID: 10157   GIDs: {50157, 3003, 1028, 1015}


[101m                          [0m Process 9718 ended


[107m                          [0m Process created for activity com.nortek.app/.ui.activity.DummyMainActivity
[107m                          [0m PID: 2840   UID: 10157   GIDs: {50157, 3003, 1028, 1015}

[31mek.app.common.ApiAgent[0m [30;104m D [0m @ Ready to send out GET_ALL_DATA : http://192.168.11.59:8083/ZWaveAPI/data/0
[37m       ActivityManager[0m [30;102m I [0m Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4181e268 time:34298679
[32mvity.DummyMainActivity[0m [30;104m D [0m @ nav item click id : 5/Camera
[33m                Volley[0m [30;101m E [0m [1] 1.onErrorResponse: Error GET_ALL_DATA :
                       [30;104m D [0m [1] Request.finish: 3076 ms: [ ] http://192.168.11.59:8083/ZWaveAPI/data/0 0x85bd6053 NORMAL 3
[34mSpannableStringBuilder[0m [30;101m E [0m SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
                       [30;101m E [0m SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
[35m      VLC/AudioService[0m [37;100m V [0m Loading position 0 in [rtsp://192.168.11.40:5454/live]
                       [37;100m V [0m Creating on-the-fly Media object for rtsp://192.168.11.40:5454/live
[36m                   VLC[0m [30;104m D [0m core libvlc: no fetch required for (null) (art currently (null))
                       [30;104m D [0m core demux meta: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 0 candidates
                       [30;104m D [0m core demux meta: no meta fetcher modules
                       [30;104m D [0m core libvlc: searching art for rtsp://192.168.11.40:5454/live
                       [30;104m D [0m core art finder: looking for art finder module matching "any": 1 candidates
                       [30;104m D [0m core art finder: no art finder modules matched
                       [30;104m D [0m core libvlc: art not found for rtsp://192.168.11.40:5454/live
[31m      VLC/LibVLC/Media[0m [30;104m D [0m Title rtsp://192.168.11.40:5454/live
                       [30;104m D [0m Artist Unknown Artist
                       [30;104m D [0m Genre Unknown Genre
                       [30;104m D [0m Album Unknown Album
[36m                   VLC[0m [30;104m D [0m core input: Creating an input for 'rtsp://192.168.11.40:5454/live'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to convert the colored shell output to html then to pdf.

Use the `ansi2html.sh` from [here](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh)

you can try smth like this

```
cat myapp_log | ansi2html.sh -p > myapp_log.html
html2any myapp_log.html file.pdf
```

Comment: I tried enscript to generate a file.ps. And open it with Preview, it translate into pdf automatically but the highlight format still gone.

Comment: can you show me the content of your log ? at least some snippet, I think pidcat standard output does not contain any info on highlights

Comment: I update my post with some snippet. I think it's kind of highlight syntax for telnet.

Comment: Updated my answer. Your log contains the shell coloring, therefor you need to convert it to smth like html, then to pdf. Let me know if your still have questions. If not you can accept the answer, if it was a solution for you :)

Comment: That's great! It worked! from html to pdf I just open it from Chrome and print it as pdf. Thanks for the script! :D

Comment: Thanks, that worked, also better to have it on a white background and not waste ink. `wkhtmltopdf` converts from html to pdf as well and is part of the debian stable repo.