# Preserve colors while piping setup script from CURL to BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl, piping

I am currently running a vbox provisioner with `curl -sSL http://goo.gl/DGs3Fv |bash` and noticed that I am losing my tty coloring while doing so. Is there anyway to fix this without porting into a variable and echoing out "after the fact"?

I've tried the answer in [Can colorized output be captured via shell redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect) but this does not seem to work in my situation. Thanks.

Quick example

[image: Run as CURL]

[image: Run as Shell]

Comment: What part of the output is supposed to be colorized? Output from some of the commands in that script?

Comment: That is correct. If for instance, the script is run as just ./setup.sh colorizing happens for yum installs, network up/down etcetra. I would like to be able to see it as if it was natively run.

Comment: That is almost certainly the tool/scripts themselves detecting the interactive mode/connected terminal/etc. of the shell they are running in.

Comment: So I would pretty much be trying to set PS1 while piping then?

Comment: Can you include the exact command you tried from the answer you linked to?

Comment: i tried `curl -sSL $URL |bash -i` but it just went haywire, also tried `script -q /dev/null $ABOVE_COMMAND` which failed

Comment: So I don't know about the other scripts but for `service` it is detecting the "console type" using `/sbin/consoletype` which returns "serial" in the piped context. I don't know what that is testing or if you can fake it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your distro's init scripts are checking stdin to determine whether to output colors to stdout, and if so that's a bug on their side.

The answer you link to is right, you should be able to work around it with `script`:

```
curl -sSL http://goo.gl/DGs3Fv | script -c 'bash' -q /dev/null
```

Running `script .. curl | bash` wouldn't work though, since it's bash and not curl you're trying to fool.