# bash - count and output lines from command

Tags: bash

I'm writing a small script that needs to run a program that outputs multiple lines, and then display the count of those lines. The program, however, can take several seconds to run and I would rather not run it twice, once for the output and another for the count.

I can do it running the program twice:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(program-command | wc -l)
program-command
printf "$count lines"
```

Is there a way to get the count and output while only running the program once? This output has formatting, so ideally that formatting (colors) would be preserved.

Comment: I know it's naive but, why not saving the output and then counting the lines? Something like `program-command > output` and then `wc -l output`

Comment: @Pie86 naive solutions can be good! I was trying to do something like that, but I was failing. I'll try using `>` as you suggested, thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `tee` and [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
program-command | tee >(wc -l)
```

To preserve color, prefix the command with `script -q /dev/null` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3515296/4070984):

```
script -q /dev/null program-command | tee >(wc -l)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben. It looks like this technically works, but loses the color formatting. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Is it possible to store the count in a bash variable(so that it can be used subsequently) without redirecting the output to a file and finding out  the value in last line. somekind of magic with BASH_REMATCH?

Comment: The braces around wc -l suggest a child shell is invoked so any value from wc -l can not be passed to avariable of parent shell..so how to store the value in a variable in parent shell.

Comment: After some hit and trial i could get the following to work. `function __RESULT { export LINE_COUNT=$(cat -);}; exec 3>&1; __RESULT < <( { cat 1.sh | tee >(wc -l 1>&2); } 2>&1 >&3 3>&-;) 3>&- ; exec 3>&-; unset -f __RESULT; echo $LINE_COUNT`

Answer (score 5):

You could use awk:

```
program-command | awk '{print $0; count++} END {print count}'
```

Comment: this is technically working, but I've lost the formatting from the command. The original output is colorized, but this produces uncolored text. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I guess this is related to `program-command` that outputs colors only when then output is passed to tty.  For example, if `program-command` would be `ls`, you should use it like this: `ls --color=always | awk '{print $0; count++} END {print count}'` (this way the colors will be preserved)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do something like that.  My personal preference is to use a file on /tmp since I mount it in memory.  This way you can write to the file and then count line and output it very quickly.

If you do no have access to a memory mounted filesystem, try using an array to hold the results so you can use the array size
`echo ${#ArrayName[@]}` and then output it `echo ${arrName[@]}`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I realized one of my goals is to preserve the color formatting of the original output. Would these solutions do that?

Answer (score 0):

After taking some insights from Ben's answer above I could get following to work:

```
$# > function getOutputAndLineCount {
       function __RESULT { export LINE_COUNT=$(cat -); }
       exec 3>&1
       __RESULT < <( { cat $1 | tee >(wc -l 1>&2); } 2>&1 >&3 3>&-;) 3>&-
       exec 3>&-
       unset -f __RESULT;
     }
$#> getOutputAndLineCount 1.sh
a
b
c
$#> echo $LINE_COUNT
3
```