# Is there a way to use `script` with shell functions? (colorized output)

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using a script to run several tests (npm, python etc...)

These have colored outputs.

I'm actually running some of these tests in parallel sending processes in the background, and capturing output in a variable to display when done (as opposed to letting the output come to TTY and having multiple outputs mixed up together).

All works well, but the output is not colored, and I would like to keep the colors. I understand it is because it is not an output to a TTY so color is stripped, and I looked for tricks to avoid this.

This answer: 
[Can colorized output be captured via shell redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect/38071740#38071740)

offers a way to do this, but doesn't work with shell functions

If I do:

```
OUTPUT=$(script -q /dev/null npm test | cat)
echo -e $OUTPUT
```

I get the output in the variable and the `echo` command output is colored.

but if f I do:

```
function run_test() { npm test; }
OUTPUT=$(script -q /dev/null run_test | cat)
echo -e $OUTPUT
```

I get:

`script: run_test: No such file or directory`

If I call the `run_test` function passing it to script like:

```
function run_test() { npm test; }
OUTPUT=$(script -q /dev/null `run_test` | cat)
echo -e $OUTPUT
```

it's like passing the output that is already eval'd without the colors, so the script output is not colored.

**Is there a way to make shell functions work with `script` ?**

I could have the script call in the function like:

```
function run_test() { script -q /dev/null npm run test | cat; }
```

but there are several issues with that:

- Sometimes I need to run multiple commands in series, and send that in the background to run in parallel, it becomes messy: I want to wrap sequences in a shell function and run that with script.
- This would already run the function itself, and return when done. What I want is pass the function to call to another function that runs in the background and logs the output with script.

PS: I also tried `npm config set color always` to force npm to always output colors, but that doesn't seem to help, plus I have other functions to call that are not all npm, so it would not work for everything anyways.

Comment: Huh? The claim that functions disrupt colorization is wrong. Plain, simply, outright, zero-truth-to-it wrong.

Comment: i didn't say functions do, simply output to a non tty does strip colors

Comment: Where does "with shell functions" factor into this question, then?

Comment: BTW -- the `function` keyword is a bashism; consider `funcname() { ...; }` without any preceding `function` to write more widely compatible code.

Comment: ...and `echo -e` is not only a bashism, but one that only works with bash under some configurations -- when the `xpg_echo` option is enabled, bash's `echo` follows the relevant POSIX standard, and `echo -e` emits `-e` as output. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections (the former of which recommends using `printf` instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a program such as `unbuffer` that simulates a TTY to get color output from software whose output is actually eventually going to a pipeline.

In the case of:

```
unbuffer npm test | cat
```

...there's a TTY simulated by `unbuffer`, so it doesn't see the FIFO going to `cat` on its output.

If you want to run a shell function behind a shim of this type, be sure to export it to the environment, as with `export -f`.

---

Demonstrating how to use this with a shell function:

```
myfunc() { echo "In function"; (( $# )) && { echo "Arguments:"; printf ' - %s\n' "$@"; }; }
export -f myfunc
unbuffer bash -c '"$@"' _ myfunc "Argument one" "Argument two"
```

Comment: i had the impression this functionality required some bash extension. is it in core bash?

Comment: It's not even an extension to bash but a completely external tool, bundled as part of `expect`. There are some lighterweight alternatives available, but nothing built into the shell.

Comment: i was responding to your original answer about `export -f `

Comment: Oh. `export -f` **is** part of bash itself. (It's not part of the POSIX sh standard, so it isn't guaranteed to work with non-bash shells; and the environment variable syntax changed in response to the shellshock vulnerability, so it's not guaranteed that exported functions will be honored by a version of bash other than the one that exported it, but it's there out-of-the-box).

Comment: (I'm... a little hard-pressed to see what making shell functions work with `script` has to do with output colorization -- perhaps that should be a separate question?)

Comment: was trying to avoid adding binaries that require different install modes on mac os and linux, but will check on `unbuffer`

Comment: re: colorization: if you know a way to output colors to a shell variable that is simpler, (see answer in original question) then please chime in on that!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect/38071740#38071740

Comment: *Ahh*. You're trying to use `script` as a replacement for `unbuffer`. That's workable, I suppose. I'll write up a description of how to make it less intrusive later.

Comment: ...significant problem there, looking into it in detail: The GNU and BSD `script` implementations are incompatible enough that being able to use them interchangeably is liable to be... sticky.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `unbuffer` and it doesn't seem to work with shell functions either

script doesn't work by passing it a shell function, however it's possible to pass some STDIN type input, so what ended up working for me was

```
script -q /dev/null <<< "run_test"
```

or

```
echo "run_test" | script -q /dev/null
```

so I could output this to a shell variable, even using a variable as the COMMAND like:

```
OUTPUT=$(echo "$COMMAND" | script -q /dev/null)
```

and later output the colored output with

```
echo -e $OUTPUT
```

Unfortunately, this still outputs some extra garbage (i.e. the shell name, the command name and the `exit` command at the end.

Since I wanted to capture the output code, I could not pipe the output somewhere else, so I went this way:

```
run() {
    run_in_background "$@" &
}    

run_in_background() {    
        COMMAND="$@" # whatever is passed to the function    
        CODE=0

        OUTPUT=$(echo "$COMMAND" | script -q /dev/null) || CODE=$(( CODE + $? ));

        echo -e $OUTPUT | grep -v "bash" | grep -v "$COMMAND";
        if [ "$CODE" != "0" ]; then exit 1; fi
    }
```

and use like:

```
# test suites shell functions
run_test1() { npm test; }
run_test2() { python manage.py test; }

# queue tests to run in background jobs
run run_test1
run run_test2
# wait for all to finish
wait
```

I'm skipping the part where I catch the errors and propagate failure to the top PID, but you get the gist.

Comment: `export -f`, once again. `unbuffer` **does** work with shell functions if you export them.

Comment: tried that: worked with script but not unbuffer... unless i'm mossing something

Comment: btw, `COMMAND="$@"` is really, **really** buggy (it's trying to stuff an array into a string, which is a less expressive data structure). Try it with a command that depends on quoting to be executed correctly.

Comment: ...see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a rundown on the caveats on putting commands in strings.

Comment: Try: `set -- printf '%s\n' "first argument" "second argument"; command="$@"` -- if you run `"$@"` you get your actual command executed, but if you run `$command` or `"$command"` you don't.

Comment: ...to generate an `eval`-safe string representing a command requires something akin to `printf -v command '%q ' "$@"`. (Without doing that you're in particularly big trouble if you're passing around filenames from an untrusted source -- consider a file created with `touch $'/uploads/$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''`).

Comment: BTW, `echo -e $OUTPUT` is string-splitting your output and passing each word as a separate argument to `echo` -- meaning that you lose information on where the linebreaks are. Also, `-e` is vanishingly unlikely to be appropriate -- nonprintable characters should already be literal rather than represented as escapes. (Note also that `echo -e` is [not specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and the standard explicitly suggests using `printf` instead).

Comment: ...as another aside, all-caps variable names are reserved for variables with meaning to the OS -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, guaranteeing that variables with at least one lowercase letter in their names are guaranteed not to have unanticipated side effects on the behavior of POSIX-standardized tools. (Setting a shell variable with a name that overlaps an existing environment variable overwrites the latter, so the namespace is necessarily shared).

Comment: thanks for the useful hints here...
unbuffer does work with the syntax you mentioned.