# How can I use the linux less command on long g++ error messages?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

So I tried somthing like this:
g++ long_error_code.cpp | less

That didn't work. I also tried redirecting to a file, but that also didn't work. So how does one handle those long error messages besides mouse scrolling thru it?

I would like a quick way to be able to move thru it and be able to search patterns like the way the command less works.

Comment: `2>&1`.........

Comment: @Steve it is really a question about how to use the shell in linux, so it belongs on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ . Unfortunately they removed the option to migrate to that site ...

Comment: Also see [Getting gcc piped-to-less to properly show colors on the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/314966/56041) and [Keep color in less after make and pipe](https://superuser.com/q/995991/173513).

Comment: Great feedback everyone, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a normal shell you can use:

```
g++ foo.cpp 2>&1  |less
```

The `>&` shell operator means to redirect the left-hand stream into the right-hand one, so this ends up with stream 1 (stdout) containing the lines that were originally in stream 2 (stderr) as well.  The `|` operation takes stream 1 of the left operand as the input for the right operand.

[According to this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/what-are-the-shells-control-and-redirection-operators), the Bash shell also allows `g++ foo.cpp |& less` .

Comment: Thanks for the explanation too, I am currently learning how to work in linux/unix.

Comment: I will lose output coloring when using `2>$1` or `|&`. Is there any fix for colors?

Comment: @JanKaifer That is a separate issue to this question so you should post a new question (or search for that same question being asked before)

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35376244/4981456