# Preserve colors of heroku logs output when piping to other command (e.g. grep)

Tags: colors, console, pipe

I am using grep to remove a lot of log noise generated e.g. by NewRelic. I do so using the following command:

```
heroku logs --force-colors -t -a myApp -s app | grep --color=never web.1
```

Unfortunately the useful coloring of the logs gets lost somewhere, and the output is uncolored.

The `--force-colors` flag should force the `heroku logs` command to output colors even when pipping the output elsewhere. the `--color=never` flag is supposed to force grep not to use their own coloring scheme.

I have tried all possible combinations with absence or presence of these two color flags, to no avail. Does anybody have a suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3515296/1175081):

```
script -q /dev/null heroku logs --force-colors -t -a myApp -s app | grep --color=never web.1
```

The color flags are no even necessary so this works as well:

```
script -q /dev/null heroku logs -t -a myApp -s app | grep web.1
```

Comment: It looks like not many people use this, but it has been very helpful for us. Thank you!

Comment: I had to use `script --flush --quiet --return /tmp/heroku-logs.txt --command "heroku logs -a app -t" > /dev/null` to first pipe it to a file with preserving colors: `tail -f /tmp/heroku-logs.txt`