# Bash: trick program into thinking stdout is an interactive terminal

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I want to run a program's output through a pipe, but it apparently behaves differently when it detects `stdout` is not an interactive shell.

How can I trick it into writing through the pipe just as it would in regular circumstances?

Comment: I have heard `expect` is a good program to do that

Comment: Also check the `script` program for that purpose: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1402389/516188

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume that the program will call the glibc function `isatty()` to check whether stdout is a terminal or not. That's common for programs which use colorized output on terminals or other features of an ANSI terminal like cursor positioning or line erasing / redrawing.

You can trick the program using the LD_PRELOAD environment variable. LD_PRELOAD is handled by the ELF linker and tells that a dynamic library should be loaded **before** all others. Using this feature it is possible to override library functions, in your case the glibc function `isatty()`. You can follow this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-glibc/index.html) for example.

I've prepared an example for you:

First create the file *libisatty.c*:

```
/**
 * Overrides the glibc function. Will always return true.
 *
 * Note: Although this should be ok for most applications it can
 * lead to unwanted side effects. It depends on the question
 * why the programm calls isatty()
 */
int isatty(int param) {
    return 1;
}
```

and compile it as a shared lib:

```
gcc -shared -o libisatty.so  libisatty.c
```

It should build fine.

Now it's time to test the library. :) I've used the command `ls --color=auto` for tests. `ls` calls `isatty()` to decide whether it should colorize it's output or not. If the output is redirected to a file or a pipe it won't be colorized. You can test this easily using the following commands:

```
ls --color=auto        # should give you colorized output
ls --color=auto | cat  # will give you monochrome output
```

Now we'll try the second command again using the LD_PRELOAD environment var:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libisatty.so ls --color=auto | cat
```

You should see colorized output.

btw cool usename: uʍop ǝpısdn !!:D

Comment: Warning: creating a shell function that does this `LD_PRELOAD` trick does not quite work, since apparently other things are other observable differences in the shell function (I'm not sure what they are). However, creating an alias `trick_tty` with `alias trick_tty="LD_PRELOAD=<full path to>/libisatty.so "` and then doing `trick_tty <cmd> | less` works.

Comment: For MacOS users, you can do the same thing but instead of setting LD_PRELOAD, you set DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES and DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE, like this: `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=./libisatty.so DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=y ls -G | cat` (note the --color flag doesn't work on mac's ls)

Answer (score 2):

Using `script` works for me:

```
script outputfile.txt yourcommand
# any output ends up in outputfile.txt
```

You could use this to pipe I guess:

```
script out.txt yourcommand ; cat out.txt | nextcommand
```

Comment: Examining the source code of `script` should reveal what other things, besides `isatty`, are used by programs to tell if they are running interactively.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
./script.sh < `tty` > output
```

If the program is doing something like `isatty(0)`, this may be enough.

Comment: Note that the programm in question will run isatty() on stdout. You pipe the terminal to stdin. This will not solve the problem

Comment: It may actually be testing stdin and not stdout

Comment: Most programs in coreutils or utils-linux are doing this. Examples: rm, mv, ls, nohup, cfdisk, more, pg, ...

Comment: please try `ls --color=auto < \`tty\` | cat` Do you see colors? Me not. (I assume that you have evaled dircolors)

Comment: Note that I have to leave for a while. Will have a look later here. Think the question is interesting. Although I believe that if the programm calls isatty on stdout it isn't easy. see you! :)

Comment: I'm not in my workstation now, but will give this a try later. _A priori_, i'm inclined to think like @hek2mgI, but who knows