# Garbled shell newlines after concurrent script execution

Tags: bash, shell, unix, makefile

I'm attempting to execute a shell script concurrently from a makefile and have all of the output go to stdout though when I do, the newlines become garbled and the only reliable fix I've found is to `reset`.

makefile:

```
all: t1 t2 t3 t4
t1 t2 t3 t4:
    @./test.sh true
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
script -q /dev/null "$@" 2>&1 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Invocation:

```
$ make -j
```

No output as you would expect, but sometimes it breaks the terminal and I have to `reset`.

Sometimes newlines and carriage returns don't work after it runs:

```
Devbox:Desktop user$ time make -j
real    0m0.019s
                user    0m0.019s
                                sys 0m0.022s
                                                Devbox:Desktop user$
```

Removing `script` from the script and replacing that line with `"$@"` allows it to work just fine, but I'm using script to preserve color output from the command.

```
LOG=$(script -q /dev/null "$@" 2>&1 | tr -d '\r' | cat)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `script` isn't the proper program here. I once gave an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14694983/171318) how to trick programs to do colorized output, even when their output goes not to a terminal using `LD_PRELOAD` and an overwritten version of the glibc function `isatty()`.

Based on that, your `test.sh` could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
output=$(LD_PRELOAD=./libisatty.so $@)
return_value=$?

echo -e "$output"
exit $return_value
```

And your `Makefile` like this:

```
all: t1 t2 t3 t4$ 
t1 t2 t3 t4:$
^I@./test.sh ls -al --color=auto$
```

Comment: the `2>&1` was for `"$@"`, but I should probably do that as well.  Unfortunately, the problem is still present even with the redirection.  I've edited my question appropriately.

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm wrong in that case. Will prepare your setup and try to reproduce.. Sounds interesting :)

Comment: Tried your setup, it gave me an interactive shell without any echo output. I could just leave this with `exit`. Can you explain in one sentence what you are trying to achieve? :) If it's just "suppressing colorized output", there are maybe better ways

Comment: I'm trying to save colorized output of a command to a variable, test a return status, and then print the output if the return status was non-zero.  I'm trying to do this concurrently from make.  Sometimes it works fine but most of the time it destroys terminal.

Comment: None of those commands, but I plan on using that sort of command with clang from a makefile.

Comment: I think I should also mention that I'm using Terminal on a Mac.  I'm actually trying it out now on ubuntu and it's not what I expected.

Comment: I'm also on Ubuntu. I'll try to find an example for you. I can only say that it will work finally.