# Locating and Editing Dynamic Symbol Table of Loaded Program?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, elf, dynamic-linking

My goal is explained in this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648919/hook-and-replace-export-function-in-the-loaded-elf-so-shared-library)

Is it possible to locate the address of a symbol's entry in the dynamic symbol table loaded into a program? 
If we can locate it, can we edit it somehow? For example if the app made the call to a function named original_func then the control should actually come to my hook_func and from there I call the original_func.

**Update:**

Some code according to the answer by 'Employed Russian':

```
extern Elf32_Dyn    _DYNAMIC[];

int i=0;
uint32_t DST_base_addr;
Elf32_Dyn *dyn;
for (dyn = _DYNAMIC; dyn->d_tag != DT_NULL; ++dyn)
{

    if(dyn->d_tag==DT_SYMTAB)
    {
        DST_base_addr=dyn->d_un.d_ptr;

        LOGE("Base address of dynamic symbol table is; 0x%x",  DST_base_addr);
        break;
    }

}
```

*Output: 0x148*

1- Not sure what that 0x148 means. It's definitely not an absolute address.

2- Also, where can I find good listing of these useful pre-defined variables such as _DYNAMIC[] _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ etc.? I wasn't very aware of such variables even when I went through ELF notes here and there.

Comment: So why you are creating new questoion ??

Comment: This question is more specific, while my previous question covered broader range.
What I asked in this question, if that's not possible then my previous question still stands; i.e. finding a solution without editing Dynamic Symbol Table.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to locate the address of a symbol's entry in the dynamic symbol table loaded into a program?

Yes, it's pretty easy: iterate over elements of the `_DYNAMIC[]` array, until you find an element with `.d_tag == DT_SYMTAB`. The `.d_un.d_ptr` of that entry will point to the dynamic symbol table in memory.

To find a specific symbol, you will also need to refer to `DT_STRTAB`.

> If we can locate it, can we edit it somehow?

Sure: it's just a memory location. You may need to `mprotect` it to be writable, but once you do, you can modify it to your heart's content.

However, most modifications will either have no effect, or cause your program to crash later.

> For example if the app made the call to a function named original_func then the control should actually come to my hook_func and from there I call the original_func.

It's pretty difficult to achieve your stated goal using this particular method, and much easier methods exist.

Perhaps you are looking for [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/building-library-interposers-for-fun-and/184404926)?

Comment: Thanks. Is_DYNAMIC[] array already defined there in the C program? Or will I have to read the data into it by parsing through ELF header?

Comment: @Usman.3D It's already defined, and initialized to overlap the `.dynamic` section of the executable.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question.  Also, I thought 'sections' only belonged to the shared library while the loaded program only had segments?