# How to get passthru to draw progress bars (e.g. w/ scp)?

Tags: php, bash, scp

I'm using [passthru](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) to run `scp`. Normally scp outputs a progress bar, but it's not being drawn when I use `passthru`. I want some estimation of how long the transfer will take. Is there a way to force it to show?

Comment: I'm sure `scp` detects its output is not PTY. You should have better luck with expect: http://php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php

Answer (score 2):

Most programs which are linked against libc use the function `isatty` to check whether stdout is a terminal before they decide to colorize their output. Thus to make sure that the ANSI terminal escape sequences will not screw up a pipe or get redirected into a file. `passthru()` will not run the command in a terminal.

In PHP you can use `proc_open()` to open a process and present it a terminal for stdout. Take this example from the manual, which I have modified to use a `pty` instead of a `pipe` for `stdout` and `stderr`:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pty", "w"),  // stdout is a pty that the child will write to
   2 => array("pty", "w")   // stderr is a pty that the child will write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('command', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
```

---

However you can also use `LD_PRELOAD` when starting a process and trick the program in a way that it *thinks* stdout is a terminal. (hackish but sometimes the last resort). I've described that here: [Bash: trick program into thinking stdout is an interactive terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690010/bash-trick-program-into-thinking-stdout-is-an-interactive-terminal/14694983#14694983)