# Log when extracting 7z archives

Tags: bash, unix

I want to create a log file whilst my script extracts 7z

I'm using the following:

```
7z x "*.7z" >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

But terminal stops displaying output and the log file is blank...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `7z` program is detecting that its stdout is not a terminal (TTY), and is choosing not to be so verbose in this case.

Unfortunately, the `7z` documentation doesn't seem to offer a "verbose" flag like many programs do.  So I'm not sure you can turn the output on easily.

But you can trick the program into thinking it has a terminal on stdout!  For example:

```
script logfile.log 7z x "*.7z"
```

For more ideas, see: [Bash: trick program into thinking stdout is an interactive terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690010/bash-trick-program-into-thinking-stdout-is-an-interactive-terminal)

Comment: But wouldn't that log the entire script?
I need to just log 7z otherwise the log will be huge, Thanks

Comment: @NeMesiS: Try it.  It will log the output from 7z.

Answer (score 0):

You're redirecting STDERR to STDOUT (that's the `2>&1`) and redirecting STDERR to the logfile. Try `7z x "*.7z" 2>&1 > logfile.log`. Hope that helps:

> % 7z c /tmp/TailsBSDPLIST.7z ~/TailsBSD > /tmp/logfile.log
>   % cat /tmp/logfile.log
>   7-Zip (a) 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03
>   p7zip Version 9.38.1 (locale=C,Utf16=off,HugeFiles=on,1 CPU)
>
> Command Line Error:
>   Unsupported command:
>   c

Comment: Thanks but I get the same problem