# How to get mongo shell output(three dot) for unterminated command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, interactive

When type a unterminated command in a mongo shell, it will return three dots indicating need more input to complete this command like below:

```
> db.test.find(
... {
...
```

I am using nodejs `child_process.spawn` to create a mongo shell process and listen on its output. I can get the standard and error output from the mongo shell but I can't get the `...` output. Below is my nodejs code:

```
const shell = spawn('mongo', params);
      shell
        .stdout
        .on('data', (data) => {
          winston.debug('get output ' + data);

        });

      shell
        .stderr
        .on('data', (data) => {
          const output = data + '';
          winston.error('get error output ', data);

        });
```

I run below code to send command on the shell:

```
shell.stdin.write('db.test.find(');
```

I wander why I can't get the `...` output on above method. Is it a special output?

**EDIT1**

I tried to use `node-pty` and `pty.js`. They can get the `...` output but they mix the input and output data together. It is not possible to separate them. 
I also tried to use `stdbuf` and `unbuffer` to disable buffer but it still doesn't work. 
It seems that nodejs child_process doesn't work well with interactive command.

Comment: What is your goal as far as spawning the `mongo` shell from Node.js? It would be much more straightforward to use the [MongoDB Node.js driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't include anything that writes to the stdin of your child process so I would be surprised if you got the ellipsis that indicates incomplete command when in fact you don't send any command at all - incomplete or otherwise.

That having been said, many command line utilities behave differently when they discover a real terminal connected to their stdin/stdout. E.g. `git log` will page the results when you run it directly but not when you pipe the results to some other command like `git log | cat` so this may also be the case here.

This can also have to do with the buffering - if your stream is line-buffered then you won't see any line that is not ended with a newline right away.

The real question is: do you see the `>` prompt? Do you send any command to the mongo shell?

Scritping interactive CLI tools can be tricky. E.g. see what I had to do to test a very simple interactive program here:

- https://github.com/rsp/rsp-pjc-c01/blob/master/test-z05.sh#L8-L16

I had to create two named pipes, make sure that stdin, stderr and stdout are not buffered, and then use some other tricks to make it work. It is a shell script but it's just to show you an example.

Comment: I sorry I didn't put the stdin source code there. When I sent `db.test.find(` on the stdin, I didn't get any output from either stdout or stderr. I do see '>' prompt but it is showing on the console not the listener method.