# Save color of the System.cmd output in placing it to IO in elixir

Tags: io, elixir, elixir-mix

I have a pretty simple mix task, actually it wraps `npm` command and returns it output to the command line:

```
defmodule Mix.Tasks.JsLint do
  use Mix.Task

  @shortdoc "Runs javascript lint"
  def run(_args) do
    System.cmd("npm", ["run", "lint"], into: IO.stream(:stdio, :line), stderr_to_stdout: true)
  end
end
```

The problem is that if I run `npm run lint` in the command line, it returns coloured output. But if I running `mix js_lint` it returns not-coloured output.

Where I loose colours? How can I fix that?

**UPDATE**
I'm using eslint.

Comment: What command does `lint` run? `eslint`? If so, try adding `--color` to the `eslint` invocation.

Comment: @Dogbert I believe the problem is deeper: `npm lint` is smart enough to see that it outputs to the pipe rather than to console to suppress colors. Basically it internally checks for `is_tty` or like, receives `false` and suppresses colors to eliminate `[^033` garbage in the log file.

Comment: @Dogbert this trick is working. Could you answer and explain how it works, please?

Comment: @mudasobwa yep, that's right, and `--color` will force enable colors in `eslint`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that most terminal applications use `isatty` (or equivalent) to check if stdout is an interactive shell, and disable colored output if it is, so that the escape sequences to change colors don't end up in your log files etc. I don't know of any simple way to spawn a process and make that process think it's attached to a terminal (there are some, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe) or using a package like [porcelain](https://github.com/alco/porcelain)), but since you're using `eslint`, you can force it to output colors even if it think it's not running interactively by passing `--color` to it. You can add that to the `"lint"` entry in `package.json`, so if your old entry was:

```
"lint": "eslint ."
```

change that to:

```
"lint": "eslint . --color"
```