# Trick an application into thinking it's a pipe, not interactive

Tags: shell

I'm looking for an opposite of this:
[Trick an application into thinking its stdin is interactive, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe)

I'd like to get the output of a command on stdout, but make it think it's writing into a pipe.

The usual solution is to `| cat` but I have the additional requirement that this is cross platform (ie `sh`, not `bash`) and returns a valid exit code if the command fails. Normally I would use pipefail but this isn't available everywhere.

I've tried various incantations of `stty` but haven't been successful.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a named pipe:

```
mkfifo tmp.pipe

# Reader runs in background
cat tmp.pipe &

# Producer in foreground
your_command > tmp.pipe
command_rtn=$?

rm tmp.pipe
```

Alternately, if you don't need the output in realtime and the output is reasonably small:

```
output=$(your_command)
command_rtn=$?
echo "${output}"
```

Or you can write the exit status to a file doing something terrible like:

```
{ your_command; echo $? > rtn_file; } | cat
command_rtn=$(cat rtn_file)
```