# pexpect's interact() reported "Inappropriate ioctl for device" when running on a VM with PowerCLI

Tags: python, python-2.7, tty, pexpect

I have a simple script (`child.py`) as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect

def ency():
    child = pexpect.spawn("cryptsetup luksChangeKey /mnt/ency")
    child.expect('Enter passphrase to be changed:')
    child.sendline('password-old')
    child.expect('Enter .*: ')
    child.sendline('password-new')
    child.expect('Verify .*: ')
    child.sendline('password-new')
    child.interact()

ency()
```

I invoke this script using a different script (`master.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
python child.py
```

The code run successfully when I run `child.py`, but when I envoke `child.py` using `master.sh`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "child.py", line 15, in <module>
    ency()
  File "child.py", line 13, in ency
    child.interact()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pexpect-4.2.1-py2.7.egg/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 740, in interact
    mode = tty.tcgetattr(self.STDIN_FILENO)
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

Note that I am invoking `master.sh` using PowerCLI. I also tried to invoke `child.py` directly using PowerCLI's `Invoke-vmscript –vm vmname –scripttext “python child.py”` and still get the same behavior.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: Is `master.py` a shell script? Why `python child.py`?

Comment: master is a python file, child is a bash script. I edited my question to reflect this. thank you for pointing this.

Comment: *master is a python file, child is a bash script*, are you sure it's not the other way around @Taleeb? Also, how do you call `master.py`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1402389/2988730. Not a dupe, just a possible solution.

Comment: @Gabriel master is shell script, I call master with `sh master.sh`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks to your link, I now see what could be causing this issue, but not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Without more info on the error I can not be sure, but for some reason it looks like the child process does not end up connected to a tty when you run it from a subshell instead of the command-line directly.

Comment: This fails for me with the error `pexpect.exceptions.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: cryptsetup.` Is there some other file needed to run this?

Comment: @Gabriel. cryptsetup is part of the LUKS management suite. If you do not have that installed, try running against some other program that you have that takes a non-trivial set of inputs.

Comment: And that's my cue to leave :) I assumed this was a simple script. Sorry I can't help you any further @Taleeb, good luck.

Comment: @Gabriel you can run almost the same script with `child = pexpect.spawn("passwd root")` it should produce similar output, of course you have to change your child expect to something similar to : `child.expect('.*: ')` Thanks

Comment: From the traceback information, it seems that the `child.interact()` call is the problem. That makes me wonder how exactly the `master.sh` script is being started? Am I correct in thinking that it is not started by you on the command line, but using some other method? In that case, at that point there simply is no terminal yet to provide interactive input. Perhaps some more background about what you're trying to accomplish can help to suggest a workaround...

Comment: @brm You are correct, I am invoking master.sh using powershell. I also tried to invoke child directly using powershell `Invoke-vmscript –vm vmname –scripttext “python child.py”` still get the same behavior.

Comment: It seems to me that inside your `master.sh` script, you should start some kind of terminal that the `client.py` program can use for interactive input. On my Linux system for example, I can use `xterm -e "python client.py"` to accomplish this. I don't know enough about powershell or about your setup in general to give a useful suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are running the `pexpect` script on a VM I suppose you don't really need to `interact` with it. So just replace

```
child.interact()
```

with

```
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)  # also use the `timeout` argument if necessary
```

to wait for the *child* to complete.

---

According to the doc, `interact()`

> gives control of the child process to the interactive user (the human **at the keyboard**). Keystrokes are sent to the child process, ...