# Live stream stdout and stdin with websocket

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket

[**online compiler**](https://compiler.programminghub.io/) this is my website where users can run console programs.

At present, the user has to enter the program input before running the program. I am trying to build live user input for the program(want to give the same experience as they run programs on their laptop).

In research to achieve this I came across a solution to **stream stdout and stdin** with **websocket**.

**My implementation**

```
# coding: utf-8
import subprocess
import thread

from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler

from nbstreamreader import NonBlockingStreamReader as NBSR


class WSHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        self.write_message("connected")
        self.app = subprocess.Popen(['sh', 'app/shell.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                    shell=False)
        self.nbsr = NBSR(self.app.stdout)
        thread.start_new_thread(self.soutput, ())

    def on_message(self, incoming):
        self.app.stdin.write(incoming)

    def on_close(self):
        self.write_message("disconnected")

    def soutput(self):
        while True:
            output = self.nbsr.readline(0.1)
            # 0.1 secs to let the shell output the result
            if not output:
                print 'No more data'
                break
            self.write_message(output)
```

nbstreamreader.py

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue, Empty


class NonBlockingStreamReader:
    def __init__(self, stream):
        '''
        stream: the stream to read from.
                Usually a process' stdout or stderr.
        '''

        self._s = stream
        self._q = Queue()

        def _populateQueue(stream, queue):
            '''
            Collect lines from 'stream' and put them in 'quque'.
            '''

            while True:
                line = stream.readline()
                if line:
                    queue.put(line)
                else:
                    raise UnexpectedEndOfStream

        self._t = Thread(target=_populateQueue,
                         args=(self._s, self._q))
        self._t.daemon = True
        self._t.start()  # start collecting lines from the stream

    def readline(self, timeout=None):
        try:
            return self._q.get(block=timeout is not None,
                               timeout=timeout)
        except Empty:
            return None


class UnexpectedEndOfStream(Exception): pass
```

shell.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "hello world"
echo "hello world"
read -p "Your first name: " fname
read -p "Your last name: " lname
echo "Hello $fname $lname ! I am learning how to create shell scripts"
```

This code streams stdout un-till shell.sh code reaches read statement.

Please guide me what wrong I am doing. Why it doesn't wait for stdin and reaches print 'No more data' before complete program executions?

Source code to test it https://github.com/mryogesh/streamconsole.git

Comment: Did you try to debug your code ? :)

Comment: Yes,. It's going inside on_message method and after thread.start_new_thread(self.soutput, ()) this statement i added print statement which means thread is not blocked.

Comment: What happend when you (after your input) hit enter on the "first name" statement? Is it simply not streamed? What happend if you go through your whole `shell.sh`, even the last `echo` isn't streamed? The issue reminds me of something (I did around a year ago exactly this, syso streaming through websocket, but currently I don't have access to that code; but I remember having problems with premature termination of the streams too).

Comment: Stream terminate as soon as it reaches read statement. output is "hello world\nhello world"

Comment: I have uploaded code on github https://github.com/mryogesh/streamconsole.git . In case you need to test code.

Comment: `while true; do  read read_user_input` ?

Comment: @dsgdfg didn't get you.

Comment: Wait user input on `bash` ! @YogeshLakhotia

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `readline()` method times out unless you send input within 100ms, which then breaks the loop. The reason you don't see the `read -p` prompt is buffering (because of readline and pipe buffering). Finally, your example javascript doesn't send a trailing newline, so `read` will not return.

If you increase the timeout, include a newline, and [find a way to work around buffering issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdin-is-interactive-not-a-pipe), your example should basically work.

I'd also use [tornado.process](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/process.html) and coroutines instead of subprocess and thread:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.process import Subprocess
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.iostream import StreamClosedError
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler


class WSHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        self.app = Subprocess(['script', '-q', 'sh', 'app/shell.sh'], stdout=Subprocess.STREAM, stdin=Subprocess.STREAM)
        IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.stream_output)

    def on_message(self, incoming):
        self.app.stdin.write(incoming.encode('utf-8'))

    @gen.coroutine
    def stream_output(self):
        try:
            while True:
                line = yield self.app.stdout.read_bytes(1000, partial=True)
                self.write_message(line.decode('utf-8'))
        except StreamClosedError:
            pass
```

Comment: well explained. Thanks for answering :)