# Why stdbuf has no effect on Python?

Tags: python, c, linux, pipe, buffer

Given the following program in Python:

```
import sys

print("input")
while True:
    pass
```

and the equivalent in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        printf("input\n");
        while(1);
        return 0;
}
```

When I pipe the program with `cat`, the output is by default buffered (instead of line-buffered). As a consequence, I have no output:

```
% python3 ./a.py | cat
(empty)

% ./a.out | cat
(empty)
```

I can use `stdbuf` to switch back to line-buffering:

```
% stdbuf -oL ./a.out | cat
input
```

But that doesn't work with Python:

```
% stdbuf -oL python3 a.py | cat
(empty)
```

Any idea why? I'm aware of the existence of `python3 -u` but I want line-buffering, not "no buffering" and I want this command line to work for other languages as well. The command `unbuffer` seems to work too, but I'd like to understand why `stdbuf` doesn't work here.

Comment: From [man stdbuf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) *NOTE: If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams ('tee' does for e.g.) then that will override corresponding settings changed by 'stdbuf'. Also some filters (like 'dd' and 'cat' etc.) don't use streams for I/O, and are thus unaffected by 'stdbuf' settings.* I guess `python` is doing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default, Python's `print()` function directs its output to [`sys.stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout), whose documentation specifies this:

> When interactive, `stdout` and `stderr` streams are line-buffered.
>   Otherwise, they are block-buffered like regular text files. You can
>   override this value with the `-u` command-line option.

Note well that those docs do not leave room for general environmental influences, such as that of the `stdbuf` command, on the buffering mode of `sys.stdout`: it is unbuffered if the `-u` option was used (or, equivalently, if environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` was set), otherwise line-buffered if interactive and block-buffered if non-interactive.

Programs can control their own buffering, as the docs of [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) acknowledge:

> NOTE: If COMMAND adjusts the buffering of its standard streams ('tee'
>   does for e.g.) then that will override corresponding settings changed
>   by 'stdbuf'. Also some filters (like 'dd' and 'cat' etc.) don't use
>   streams for I/O, and are thus unaffected by 'stdbuf' settings.

Since Python explicitly specifies buffering details, it is reasonable to expect that it in fact does affirmatively manage its buffering, thus mooting any effect of `stdbuf`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `python` decides whether to use buffering or not based on `isatty`.

I used this script (from [Trick an application into thinking its stdout is a terminal, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401002/trick-an-application-into-thinking-its-stdout-is-a-terminal-not-a-pipe)):

```
faketty() {
    script -qfc "$(printf "%q " "$@")" /dev/null
}
```

And it works:

```
% faketty python3 a.py | cat
input
```

(And it's line-buffered)

Comment: You are my hero