# capturing text from scp to variable or array

Tags: linux, bash, variables, redirect, scp

I'm trying to capture the output of an scp command to a variable or array in Bash.
I'm not exactly sure where the text comes from local or remote ?

So far I've tried the following :

```
#!/bin/bash -x 

mytty=$(tty)
echo "mytty is ${mytty}"
myvar=$(scp  test.js  crashdog@webserver.com:/home/crashdog 2>&1 > $mytty)
echo "myvar is ${myvar}"
```

I can see the text on my tty like follows:

```
test.js                                                                                                 100% 1200     1.2KB/s   00:00
```

But myvar remains empty. So my two questions, where is above text coming from ? and how can I assign the text to a variable or array in Bash.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `scp` doesn't output anything when its stdout isn't the terminal.

To trick it you can use `script`:

```bash
out=$(script -qefc "scp test.js crashdog@webserver.com:/home/crashdog" /dev/null)

echo "$out"
```

You can find more info about it in [How to trick an application into thinking its stdout is a terminal, not a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1401002/3387716)