# Expecting input from std::cin (Unix C++)

Tags: c++, linux, unix, command-line, pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if stdin is a terminal or pipe in C/C++/Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe-in-c-c-qt)

I'm writing a command line application that expects data as either a command line argument, or from cin.

Is there a way to check if the user piped some data in the application ($ ./myapp < test.txt), and only display a prompt for keyboard input if not?

If I'm checking for !cin.good() / cin.eof() etc., the prompt will never appear.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe-in-c-c-qt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
isatty(STDIN_FILENO)
```

will return whether standard input is a terminal (tty), i.e. interactive.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something with fstat(2) and S_ISFIFO?