# Stdin is from keyboard or from a file

Tags: c, stdin

Can a program detect if it's stdin is
coming from keyboard input vs. being
redirected from a file? in c ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if stdin is a terminal or pipe in C/C++/Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe-in-c-c-qt)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, on most systems.  On POSIX systems (Linux, Mac OS X, BSD, plus many more), you can use the [`isatty(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) function on file descriptor 0 (standard input).  On Windows, you can use [`_isatty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4s0ddew%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  For example:

```
if(isatty(0))
{
    // standard input is a terminal device
}
```

Note that many programs use `isatty` to alter their output buffering behavior: if standard output is a terminal, the output is line buffered (e.g. it's flushed after every newline gets printed), whereas if standard output is not a terminal, it's fully-buffered (e.g. it's flushed only when the buffer becomes full, the process exits normally, or the stream is explicitly flushed by the application).