# How to read piped content in C?

Tags: c, stdin, pipe

I want to be able to do this:

```
$ echo "hello world" | ./my-c-program
piped input: >>hello world<<
```

I know that [`isatty` should be used](http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/isatty.html) to detect if stdin is a tty or not. If it’s not a tty, I want to read out the piped contents — in the above example, that’s the string `hello world`.

What’s the recommended way of doing this in C?

Here’s what I got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  if (!isatty(fileno(stdin))) {
    int i = 0;
    char pipe[65536];
    while(-1 != (pipe[i++] = getchar()));
    fprintf(stdout, "piped content: >>%s<<\n", pipe);
  }

}
```

I compiled this using:

```
gcc -o my-c-program my-c-program.c
```

It *almost* works, except it always seems to add a U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER and a newline (I do understand the newline though) at the end of the piped content string. Why does this happen, and how can this issue be avoided?

```
echo "hello world" | ./my-c-program
piped content: >>hello world
�<<
```

**Disclaimer:** I have no experience with C whatsoever. Please go easy on me.

Comment: @H2CO3 Why did you remove your answer? It was the only one explaining what was happening. Or was it incorrect?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The replacement symbol shows up because you forgot to NUL-terminate the string.

The newline is there because by default, `echo` inserts `'\n'` at the end of its output.

If you want to not insert `'\n'` use this:

```
echo -n "test" | ./my-c-program
```

And to remove the wrong character insert

```
pipe[i-1] = '\0';
```

before printing the text.

Note that you need to use `i-1` as the null character because the way you implemented your loop test. In you code `i` is incremented once more after the last char.

Comment: Both `pipe[i-1] = '\0'` and `pipe[i-1] = 0;` seem to work. Thank you!