# Is there an elegant way to determine if an ifstream is attached to stdin?

Tags: c++, linux, unix

My program is a common shell that I am trying to write in C++.  In addition to taking commands from the command line it has to be able to read commands in a file - the file name being passed as an optional arg, not by redirection.

If the arg is present I open the passed filename otherwise I open "/dev/stdin".  I'm not thrilled about opening the dev file and it isn't my main question but if someone has a better method I would love to hear it.

Eventually I have to read commands given to the shell but first I must present the prompt if it I am reading from stdin or skip the prompt if the input is coming from a file.  My question is: is there a better way to determine in `getCommand` if the input stream is stdin than declaring a global or passing a bool or similar hacks?

It occurs to me that if I can somehow use std::cin rather than opening the /dev file I can pass the stream as an `istream`.  Would that make it easier to distinguish between the two?  E.G. `if (source == cin)` ?

Thanks for any and all suggestions.

```
bool getCommand(ifstream source, std::string command)
{
    if (source == stdin)
        //print prompt to stdout

    // do the rest of stuff

    return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input;
    std::string command;

    if (argc == 2)
    {
        input.open(argv[1], std::ifstream::in);

        if (! input)
        {
            perror("input command file stream open");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        input.open("/dev/stdin", std::ifstream::in);

        if (! input)
        {
            perror("input stdin stream open");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    //.......

    if (getCommand(input, command))
        //.......
}
```

Comment: "I must present the prompt if it I am reading from stdin" -- this seems to be the wrong condition. You should present the prompt if you're reading from a terminal. It's just anti-social to write special code to *stop* someone piping or redirecting input into your program :-)

Comment: Yes, look for input being a terminal. You can use the source code to bash to find the functions to use. Or strace a bash shell to see what it calls to check file descriptor 0.

Comment: There are many other problems in your example code too. Passing std::ifstream by value, not passing std::string by reference when it's an out param.

Comment: Also, you should be able to achieve what u want without doing an open on '/dev/stdin', without much difficulty.

Comment: Yes, thanks to everyone for their input.  There is no restriction on stdin versus tty and I appreciate the correction.  I will incorporate the distinctions into the project and use the info in the answers to overcome my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `std::istream&` as the type of your variable then you can use `std::cin` instead of opening `/dev/stdin`:

```
std::ifstream fileinput;
if (argc == 2)
{
    fileinput.open(argv[1], std::ifstream::in);

    if (! fileinput)
    {
        perror("input command file stream open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
std::istream &input = (argc == 2) ? fileinput : std::cin;
```

The remainder of your question *should* be about identifying a tty ([Detect if stdin is a terminal or pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922)). But failing that, once you've made the above change you could compare with the address of `std::cin`:

```
if (&input == &std::cin) {
    std::cout << "prompt:";
}
```

Obviously that won't identify the case where the command line argument is `/dev/stdin`, so it's a bit of a bodge. But I'd probably argue that's actually an improvement given the funny requirement, because someone can at least write `yourprogram /dev/stdin < input.txt`, or `sort input.txt | yourprogram /dev/stdin` in order to work around your restriction and avoid the prompt :-)

Answer (score 2):

First off, if you want to read either from `std::cin` or from a `std::ifstream`, I would implement the work in terms of an `std::istream` and certainly avoid opening `/dev/stdin`:

```
std::istream  in(std::cin.rdbuf());
std::ifstream fin;
if (argc == 2) {
    fin.open(av[1]);
    // check that the file is actually open or produce an error
    in.rdbuf(fin.rdbuf());
}
else {
    // determine if you need to create a prompt
}

if (getCommand(in, command)) {
    ...
}
```

Now, to determine if you actually need to write a prompt it isn't sufficient to determine if you are reading from standard input but you also need to determine if the standard input is connected to something with a screen and a keyboard. There is no portable way to do so, however. On UNIXes there are functions like `isatty()` which can be used to determine if file descriptor 0 is connected to a tty. I would use this information to set up an `iword()` which can then be used to check if the stream need a prompt:

```
static int const needs_prompt = std::ios_base::xalloc();
...
in.iword(needs_prompt) = isatty(0);
...
if (in.iword(needs_prompt)) {
    std::cout << "pompt>";
}
```

If you want to get fancy you can create a custom `std::streambuf` which is hooked up with an `std::ostream` which is `tie()`ed to the input stream stream and writes a prompt upon `sync()`: Every time a read operation on an input stream is done the `tie()`ed `std::ostream` is flushed. However, this requires that you only read once for each prompt being produced, e.g. using `std::getline(in, line)`. Obviously, if you don't need a prompt, you don't `tie()` an `std::ostream`. Below is a simple program demonstrating the auto-prompt approach (without doing any of the other business):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <streambuf>

struct prompt
    : std::streambuf
{
    std::string   d_prompt;
    std::ostream& d_out;
    prompt(std::string const& p, std::ostream& out)
        : d_prompt(p)
        , d_out(out)
    {
    }
    int sync() {
        this->d_out << this->d_prompt << std::flush;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    prompt       p("prompt>", std::cout);
    std::ostream helper(&p);
    std::cin.tie(&helper);

    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {
        std::cout << "read '" << line << "'\n";
    }
}
```