# Is this elegant way to open stdin or a file legal?

Tags: c++, cin, istream

I've recently had to implement the common pattern of reading from a file or, given a filename of "-", from stdin. There is an abundance of solutions on SO, but I found mine to be shorter.

```
string from (some arg);
ifstream fromfile;
istream& read = (from == "-")
    ? cin
    : (fromfile.open(from), fromfile);
```

Key part is moving `fromfile.open` to a branch. This lets us use a reference instead of a pointer while avoiding checking for equality with "-" twice, which happens in most other solutions.

However, I did not find this kind of approach used anywhere else. I presume that is mainly because  it is somewhat harder to read. Or is there something else?

Comment: shorter != more elegant

Comment: @SuperStormer Certainly not in general. But in this case it is short and still easy to read (I think?)

Comment: *This lets us use a reference instead of a pointer while avoiding checking for equality with "-" twice* where does this check normally happen twice? Can you provide an example of this?

Comment: It is legal. Do you have any particular concerns?

Comment: @JohnFilleau similarly to e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19171123/39590, assigning to the `istream&` is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @Eugene I do not. Just a bit confused because I could not find this pattern being used.

Comment: Personally, I don't consider this code to be elegant at all (more like "short and ugly") and would never use this form.   Code which defines a variable that is potentially never used more effort than alternatives to reason about what it does.

Comment: This is one of those situations where a pointer feels more appropriate than a reference. Wrap it in a singleton-type function, and then use only takes one line of code.

Comment: @Peter Regarding the variable that is never used, I don't think that can be avoided?

Comment: @mafu - Not with your approach, no.   With alternatives to achieve the same effect -  which you claim to have read - it can.