# How to pass a filename when executing a C program

Tags: c, bash, terminal, arguments, command-line-arguments

I am trying to not hardcode the name of the input file in my C program. I have all of the other components working when I hardcode the filename. But would like to be able to pass it a string filename.
I am trying to execute compile a file called `Matrix.c` and name its executable `matrix`.

So, in terminal, when I get to my working directory.

```
gcc -g Matrix.c -o matrix
```

then when I compile

```
./matrix
```

It doesn't have a filename passed to it so I am gonna check for that and have the user input a filename to load.

However, when someone passes the filename, should it be passed as:

```
./matrix filename.txt
```

or

```
./matrix < filename.txt
```

With the latter option, I can't seem to get the name of the argument passed to the function from `argv[1]` — it's just "(Null)".

I know this is very simplistic question. But am I just completely off my rocker? Is it something to do with me running on OS X El Capitan. I know I've used the '<' convention before.

Comment: I've looked around and there are quite a few different solutions, and different ways to handle it.

Comment: can you show us the code of `matrix.c` ? Redirecting with `<` doesn't require any extra argument but your reading of `stdin` using `scanf`, `gets`, whatever like you were working on standard input.

Comment: When you use < you are redirecting the input from your filename to your program.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is how the shell works, mainly.  When you use:

```
./matrix filename.txt
```

then the program is given two arguments — the program name and the file name.  When you use:

```
./matrix < filename.txt
```

then the program is given just one argument — the program name — and the shell arranges for its standard input to come from the file (and the file name is not passed to your program).

Either can be made to work; you just have to decide which you want to support.  What should happen if the user types `./matrix file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`?  One version of conventional behaviour would be to process each file in turn, writing each set of results to standard output.  There are plenty of alternative behaviours — most of them have been used by someone at some time or another.  Reading from standard input when there is no file name specified is a common mode of operation (think `cat` and `grep` and …).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I just fixed it and tried to address all three modes of input. Thanks

Comment: I frequently use functions similar to `int processor(FILE *fp, const char *fn)` which reads the input from the stream `fp` which is the opened file `fn` (or a pseudo-name for 'standard input'), sometimes using an extra argument `FILE *ofp` to specify which file the output should be written to. The return value is 0 for 'success' and anything else for failure.  The code in your main program can then call `processor()` quite easily.  Indeed, I have a set of functions that handle the processing for zero or more residual arguments, so `main()` ends `return filter(argc, argv, optind, processor);`.

Comment: `isatty()` can be useful here, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe-in-c-c-qt

Answer (score 0):

Arguments to a command are in argv[1 .. argc-1].

The redirect from '<' sends the contents of the file to the program's stdin.

A third way to get the filename would be to print "Enter filename: " and then read the string typed by the user.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I just fixed it and tried to address all three modes of input. Thanks