# What are the differences between running a shell (e.g., sh) through a TTY, PTY, or execv() using pipes?

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, shell

> What are the differences between running a shell (e.g., sh) through a TTY, PTY, or execv() using pipes?

I've wondered what are the differences between invoking a shell, e.g., `sh` through a TTY (terminal) or PTY(pseudoterminal), or from C-program using `execv()` and pipes for stdin/stdout/stderr?

In particular, I'm interested in the differences between TTY/PTY and the C-program, since TTY and PTY should behave identical?

Invoking `sh` through a TTY/PTY, then this (pseudo)terminal interpret/convert the input before sending it `sh`. Likewise, it echoes the output from `sh` to the screen of the terminal? Is this the stdout of the (pseudo)terminal?

Are the only differences between TTY/PTY and C-program that the TTY/PTY acts as a "layer" of communication between the process sending/receiving data to `sh`, or are there other differences?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need `isatty` or `fstat` to see the difference.

Take a look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601564/1336858