# Parsing linux color control sequences

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm trying to render the output of a linux shell command in HTML. For example, `systemctl status mysql` looks like this in my terminal:

[image]

As I understand from [Floz'z Misc](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) I was expecting that the underlying character stream would contain control codes. But looking at it in say `hexyl` (`systemctl status mysql | hexyl`) I can't see any codes:

[image]

Looking near the bottom on lines 080 and 090 where the text "Active: failed" is displayed, I was hoping to find some control sequences to change the color to red. While not necessarily ascii, I used some [ascii tables](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) to help me:

- looking at the second lot of 8 characters on line 090 where the letters `ive: fa` are displayed, I find:
- 69 = i
- 76 = v
- 65 = e
- 3a = :
- 20 = space
- 66 = f
- 61 = a
- 69 = i

There are no bytes for control sequences.

I wondered if hexyl is choosing not to display them so I wrote a Java program which outputs the raw bytes after executing the process as a bash script and the results are the same - no control sequences.

The Java is roughly:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "systemctl status mysql"}); // runs in the shell
p.waitFor();
byte[] bytes = p.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
for(byte b : bytes) {
    System.out.println(b + "\t" + ((char)b));
}
```

That outputs:

```
...
32   
32   
32   
32   
32   
65  A
99  c
116 t
105 i
118 v
101 e
58  :
32   
102 f
97  a
105 i
108 l
101 e
100 d
...
```

**So the question is:** How does bash know that it has to display the word "failed" red?

Comment: Most applications that print colour (using what are called ANSI escape codes, btw) will detect when they aren’t printing to a terminal, e.g. when being piped somewhere, and _not_ print colour.

Comment: Check out the `colorized-logs` package, which includes a number of useful tools, including `ansi2html`. It's in repos like Ubuntu etc, and https://github.com/kilobyte/colorized-logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systemctl` *detects* that the output is not a terminal, and it removes colors codes from the output.

Related: [Detect if stdin is a terminal or pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312922/detect-if-stdin-is-a-terminal-or-pipe) , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249723/how-to-trick-a-command-into-thinking-its-output-is-going-to-a-terminal  , https://superuser.com/questions/1042175/how-do-i-get-systemctl-to-print-in-color-when-being-interacted-with-from-a-non-t

Tools sometimes (sometimes not) come with options to enable color codes always, like `ls --color=always`, `grep --color=always` on in case of systemd with `SYSTEMD_COLORS` environment variable.

---

> What tool can I use to see them?

You can use `hexyl` to see them.

> how does bash know that it has to mark the word "failed" red?

Bash is the shell, it is completely unrelated.

Your *terminal*, the graphical window that you are *viewing* the output with, knows to mark it red because of ANSI escape sequences in the output. There is no interaction with Bash.

---

```
$ SYSTEMD_COLORS=1 systemctl status dbus.service | grep runn | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 20 20 20 41 63 74  69 76 65 3a 20 1b 5b 30  |     Active: .[0|
00000010  3b 31 3b 33 32 6d 61 63  74 69 76 65 20 28 72 75  |;1;32mactive (ru|
00000020  6e 6e 69 6e 67 29 1b 5b  30 6d 20 73 69 6e 63 65  |nning).[0m since|
00000030  20 53 61 74 20 32 30 32  32 2d 30 31 2d 30 38 20  | Sat 2022-01-08 |
00000040  31 39 3a 35 37 3a 32 35  20 43 45 54 3b 20 35 20  |19:57:25 CET; 5 |
00000050  64 61 79 73 20 61 67 6f  0a                       |days ago.|
00000059
```

Comment: awesome thanks - by setting the environment I now get the control sequences, thanks!