# Why does wc output different padding spaces depending on how stdin is connected?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin, wc

See the following two commands with output:

```
$ wc < myfile.txt
 4  4 34
$ cat myfile.txt | wc
      4       4      34
```

My understanding is that these two both connect the stdin of the `wc` process with the content stream of `myfile.txt`. But why is the output padded in one case, and not in the other? How does wc tell the difference between the two? Is it not just reading from stdin?

Comment: [wc's source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c) and [Methods in Detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7601564/3776858) might help.

Comment: current [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html) says format should be `"%d %d %d %s\n", <newlines>, <words>, <bytes>, <file>` but I don't know any implementations that do that

Comment: I could reproduce it with the `wc` from GNU tools, while i.e. the BSD `wc` (the one which comes with _macos_) produces output in identical format. Technically speaking, a program can detect whether the input is a file or a pipe, and therefore can react differently in those cases. I don't know why the implementors of `wc` decided to produce different formats in both cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: because with `wc < myfile.txt`, the `wc` program has direct access to the file, and can do things besides reading from it. Specifically, it can get the file's size (and it bases the output column width on that). With `cat myfile.txt | wc`, it can't do that, so it uses wide columns to make sure there's enough room.

Long answer: `wc` tries to provide nicely columnated output:

```
$ wc a.txt b.txt 
   6    6   88 a.txt
  60  236 1772 b.txt
  66  242 1860 total
```

In order to estimate how wide its columns need to be, the GNU version of `wc` [runs `stat()` (or `fstat()`) on all of its input files](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c#L722) (before actually reading them to get the detailed counts), and [uses their sizes to determine how large the word/line/character counts might get](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/wc.c#L749), and hence how wide it might need to make the columns to have room for all those digits.

If it can't get any of the input files' sizes (e.g. because they're not plain files, but pipes or something similar), it "assumes the worst", and forces a minimum width of 7 digits. So anytime *any* of the inputs are pipes or anything like that, you're going to get at-least-7-character-wide columns.

Some examples:

```
# direct input via stdin
$ wc a.txt - <b.txt
   6    6   88 a.txt
  60  236 1772 -
  66  242 1860 total

# indirect input via cat and a pipe on stdin
$ cat b.txt | wc a.txt -
      6       6      88 a.txt
     60     236    1772 -
     66     242    1860 total

# direct via file descriptor #4
$ wc a.txt /dev/fd/4 4<b.txt
   6    6   88 a.txt
  60  236 1772 /dev/fd/4
  66  242 1860 total

# indirect input via cat and a pipe on FD #63
$ wc a.txt <(cat b.txt)
      6       6      88 a.txt
     60     236    1772 /dev/fd/63
     66     242    1860 total
```

Comment: @Cyrus  for `wc < file`, the shell opens the file on fd=0 (stdin) and passes (with `exec()` family syscalls) the fd to `wc`, then `wc` can call `fstat()` on the fd to get the file's info (e.g. file size).

Comment: for `wc < file`, the shell never reads data from the file, it only opens the file.