# How do I redirect std::cout with a carriage return `\r` to a file?

Tags: c++

Here is a sample code:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
  using std::cout;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
    cout << "\r" << "Processing req. " << i << std::flush;
  }
  cout << std::endl;
}
```

After I run it `clang++ stdout.cc && ./a.out > output`, the `output` file has gibberish that I don't care about. This is what it looks like:
[image]

I am fine with having just `Processing req. 4` as output or none at all.
Do you think of an elegant way of handling this?

Comment: FWIW, everything is working correctly. All C++ can do is write bytes to the output stream. Whether certain bytes have special meaning (e.g. make a beeping noise, or move the cursor to the start of the line) is entirely up to whatever program reads the output (like your terminal). If you redirect the output to a file, there is no program to interpret it. It just gets written verbatim, byte for byte.

Comment: You'd have to do buffering on your own that interprets character `\r` and removes characters from the end until `\n`/begin. But, in general, I wouldn't consider that to be a good idea. Output stream should be just that, a stream of bytes going out of the program. The bytes should not be subject of change if any future write happens, because that quickly becomes a jumbled mess.

Comment: Potentially related: [Detect if stdin is a terminal or pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1312922/11082165). You could modify the output of your program depending on where it thinks the output is going.